# Java - listeners in Swing

Tags: java, swing, listener

I am starting to write some code in Java Swing and I am getting a little bit mixed up in the hierarchy of listeners that swing offers. Namely I wanted to know when to use, for instance, an `ActionListener` over `ListSelectionListener` and how to differentiate when a particular listener gets called from the UI i.e. after what user interaction.

Thanks very much for your responses.

Comment: The listeners will always be called from the objects you attatched it too. To diferentiate which UI element is the element throwing the event you can use the source field from the event class giving to the listener.

Comment: WOuld you give a short example on how to give the element to the listener? SOrry, I am a very beginner at this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About `ActionListener`

> An action event occurs, whenever an action is performed by the user.
>   Examples: When the user clicks a button, chooses a menu item, presses
>   Enter in a text field. The result is that an actionPerformed message
>   is sent to all action listeners that are registered on the relevant
>   component. [reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

About `ListSelectionListener`

> List selection events occur when the selection in a list or table is
>   either changing or has just changed. List selection events are fired
>   from an object that implements the ListSelectionModel interface. To
>   get a table's list selection model object, you can use either
>   getSelectionModel method or getColumnModel().getSelectionModel(). [reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html)

Q. how to differentiate when a particular listener gets called from the UI i.e. after what user interaction.

The above details and the references contains much information to get start with.

Answer (score 0):

`ActionListener` is used e.g. for `JButton`, it tells just that the GUI-element has done something (a button can not do anything except be clicked).

`ListSelectionListener` contains more information (which element has been choosen).

For more information on when to use which `Listener` check the javadoc of the element you want to use.